# entering data in to database with java

Tags: java, jdbc, combobox, boolean

I have a form i am entering in to database.

The values are from 0 to 10

0 through 8 are text fields and i have no problems there.

9 is a combo box which I am having problems with

10 is a bool value which starts as one in the database so I am calling that false.

How do I,

add the combobox value to my string? and make sure the value of the bool is added based on the value of there selection of the combobox?

for instance the combobox allows four options specifying the relationship of the person your adding.

```
 private void Cmd_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        try {
          String sql ="Insert Into contact (id, Business_Name, First_Name, Last_Name, Phone, Email, Address_Line_1, Address_Line_2, Website, Relationship) value (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
          pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

          pst.setString(1,tb0.getText());
          pst.setString(2,tb1.getText());
          pst.setString(3,tb2.getText());
          pst.setString(4,tb3.getText());
          pst.setString(5,tb4.getText());
          pst.setString(6,tb5.getText());
          pst.setString(7,tb6.getText());
          pst.setString(8,tb7.getText());
          pst.setString(9,tb8.getText());
          pst.setString(10,tb9.getSelectedItem().toString());

          rs = pst.executeQuery();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);  
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Where is the bool value in the database? Is it a column in "Contact" table?

Comment: Yes everything is on contact table. Bool value is named Answer. I will try the suggestion getselelected item to string in the morning when I'm back at office

Comment: Does the book value need to be in my string? Or does it just apply automatic?

Comment: @ Ask Thakare your suggestion worked perfectly but I still get a Exception e by value. is this because I need to enter my bool in somehow?

Comment: I added my recent code. Combobox toString worked I think its the bool missing that is still causing me problems.

Comment: @ask Thakare. Make an answer when you get a chance and I will accept. thanks for you help. I will start a new thread for the other question.